# How to show view display if one field value is higher than another value

Tags: php, drupal, view, drupal-views

I have a content type with 2 computed fields - I want to show 2 different views depending on which field is highest. Is this possible with views? I've had a look at the arguments section, but to be honest I am not 100% sure what I should be looking for.

Any help would be mucho appreciated, thanks

Edit - Am working with Drupal and Drupal Views

Comment: Could you post the code you talking about please?

Comment: There is no code - I just need to know if there is a way to show a view based on which computed field value is the highest.

Comment: You should show us the context type (as an example) and clarify what you mean by "view" and by "content type".

Comment: sorry I thought if my question was tagged as Drupal and Drupal views it would be clear that it is that I am working with.  Have edited the original post.

Comment: I'm not good at Drupal. Sorry. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I am not sure where you want to show the view. I am going to assume in the content type.

Steps:

```
1) Create the template file. YOUR-CONTENT-TYPE.tpl.php
2) Write the if statement to validate which view you want to use
3) Then use views_embed_view($name, $display_id = 'default')
```

If you are still lost then ping me.